# Descriptions for ViewAssertion in Espresso

Tags: android, kotlin, android-testing, android-espresso

I have this code:

```
onView(withId(R.id.my_view)).check(matches(isDisplayed()))
```

How can I add my own message to it in case of a fall of the test with an error?
For example as in junit:

```
assertEquals("My message", expected, actual)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write your own custom matcher. The following code will check the hint in a EditText. Check out [this](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing/tree/master/ui/espresso/CustomMatcherSample) example:

```
private Matcher<View> withHint(final Matcher<String> stringMatcher) {
    checkNotNull(stringMatcher);
    return new BoundedMatcher<View, EditText>(EditText.class) {

        @Override
        public boolean matchesSafely(EditText view) {
            final CharSequence hint = view.getHint();
            return hint != null && stringMatcher.matches(hint.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void describeTo(Description description) {
            description.appendText("YOUR WHATEVER CUSTOM MESSAGE");
            stringMatcher.describeTo(description);
        }
    };
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own custom method like isVisible(int id) whose implementation would be something like this:

```
public boolean isVisible(int elementId) {
 try {
  onView(withId(R.id.elementId)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
  return true;
} catch(Throwable t) {
   return false;
}
}
```

And your assertion in your test would look something like this:

```
assertEquals("My failure message", expected, isVisible(R.id.someID));
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use Espresso .withFailureHandler() and writing a generic failure handler that will make the test fail using the fail(String; Method.

More this failure handler here:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/ViewInteraction.html#withFailureHandler(android.support.test.espresso.FailureHandler)